# SCCM 2012 R2 - OSD Task Sequence failure on physical computers

Tags: log-files, drivers, sccm, sccm-2012, windows

I'm trying to deploy windows 7 with SCCM 2012 R2 to physical desktops and laptops. But the task sequence keeps failing, no matter what I try. When I try it on a VM it works fine. However, when I try it on a physical computer it fails. So I think it has something to do with drivers, but I already tried both the "auto apply drivers" + wmi query for model method, and also the "apply driver package" + wmi query for model method.

In the link below I added a zip file, containing two other zip files. One is a captured log from a failed osd on a desktop, the other is the export of my task sequence.

[Download zip-file with log and TS](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ces97zrt7gu37t6/Task%20sequence%20export.zip)

If anyone could resolve the issue, or share their own task sequence for such a task (pure sccm 2012 (R2), no MDT), that would be great.

If anyone knows a website with an active SCCM-community where my chances of getting a respone are bigger, that would also be nice.

Comment: What's in your "Setupact.log" file on a failed machine? That's going to give you more detail about what's failing.

Comment: Are you Deploying using PXE, Media, or What?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I hope that you're aware of the "Configuration Manager Trace Log Tool", `cmtrace.exe` this is SCCM's log viewer app and makes trawling through these log files and spotting errors much, much easier. You should find cmtrace.exe on your site server in the `Microsoft Configuration Manager\Tools` folder, it's a standalone, portable EXE with no install that you can just copy to any other machine that you'll be viewing log files on and run.

From your "smsts-20140606-233241.log" you're getting an error in the "Setup Windows and Configuration Manager" step of your task sequence.

> Windows setup failed, code 31

This "Setup Windows and Configuration Manager" step as well as installing the Configuration Manager client (which is what it looks like it does) is also the step that runs the Windows setup and applies all of your initial Windows OS configuration (which you've probably defined in earlier steps like the "Apply Windows Settings" and "Apply Network Settings" steps, but wasn't actually applied to the OS until now.

As Evan Anderson says in his comment, the `C:\Windows\Setupact.log` will give you a lot more information about what is happening during this step, and what is going wrong, but quick things you can check are the settings defined in the "Apply Windows Settings" and "Apply Network Settings" steps, particularly things like the Windows Product Key.